# Oracle sql to find difference between the average and the lowest average

Tags: sql, oracle

4. (Easy) Find the difference between each student’s average grade and the best average grade in his group.
   pls help....
   i am trying hard to figure out the problem still not solved.
   i should use partition function and how to generate the differences between the best student average in a group to that of the lower grades students.

this is my query,,

```
**select 
students.st_id,students.st_group,
rank() over (partition by students.st_group order by avg(grades.g_grade) desc ) as ranking ,
lead(avg(grades.g_grade), 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY students.st_group ORDER BY avg(grades.g_grade) DESC NULLS LAST) DifferencebetweenHigheraverage,
avg(grades.g_grade)
from grades left join students on grades.g_student=students.st_id 
group by students.st_id,students.st_group
having students.st_group in (1,2,3);**
```

Pls help.......[image]

Answer (score 0):

if in the table STUDENT_GRADES, i have attributes

1. ST_ID
2. ST_GROUP
3. ST_GRADE

select query to get student's difference from maximum grade among his group is

`with MAXGRADES as (select ST_GROUP, max(ST_GRADE) as MAX from STUDENT_GRADES)
select ST_ID, ST_GRADE - MAX as DIFF from STUDENT_GRADES inner join MAXGRADES using(ST_GROUP)`